# Weird output at the end of string in Ubuntu terminal

Tags: c++, string, ubuntu, terminal, char

I was trying C++ in Ubuntu terminal. I am getting weird symbols at the end of strings.(This also happened in the past in Codeblocks for Ubuntu but everything worked fine in Codeblocks Windows).

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char name[20];
    cout << "\nEnter name: ";
    cin.getline(name, 20);
    cout << "\nHello ";
    cout.write(name, 20);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Enter name: Yash

Hello Yash�@��Fy
```

I have checked other threads with the same problem. All of them had assignment problems where the users did not add '\0' at the end. But here I am doing no such thing. Then why do I get these characters at the end?

Comment: OT remark: If your teachers are actually still using Turbo C++ and teach you to use `char[]` as strings, you should probably get a good and up to date book if you want to get into programming outside school. That `char[]` business is not good C++.

Comment: @BaummitAugen I am trying to improve. I already have the C++ Primer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cout.write(name, 20);
```

will (try to) write exactly 20 characters, it will not check for `'\0'`. You can check such things in your [favorite reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write).

If you really want to use a `char[]` for this, you should just write

```
cout << name;
```

That will check for the terminating character.

However, it would be better to just ditch the C-style strings and move to `std::string` instead:

```
int main () {
    std::string name;
    std::cout << "\nEnter name: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, name);
    std::cout << "\nHello ";
    std::cout << name;
}
```

Comment: @Yashbhatt I would hope so, but one can never be sure as TurboC++ is older than C++ itself. You should consider moving to a compiler from this decade.

Comment: I try explaining this to my school folks every time.

Comment: @Yashbhatt Ah, I see. All of the above is legal in the oldest version of C++, and it is quite basic stuff too. So there is a decent chance it will work on Turbo C++.

Comment: Works fine in Turbo C++. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To understand this better, you're never initializing the `char name` to 0, and `cout.write()` does not check for `null`. One option is to initialize `char name` to `0`s from the start:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char name[20] = {0};
    cout << "\nEnter name: ";
    cin.getline(name, 20);
    cout << "\nHello ";
    cout.write(name, 20);
    return 0;
}
```

@BaummitAugen's answer is the proper way to do this, though.

Comment: You don't need to initialize `name` to 0, `getline` will write a `'\0'` after the end of the input.

Comment: But like I said, `cout.write()` ignores the `\0`s. If it's all zeroed this won't be a problem.

Comment: But it does not ignore the `\0`, it will just print them. So this is just a little bit better than before. Well, at least no more UB.